# Can you create a firestore Timestamp with firebase-admin-node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In the client js SDK, you can do the following:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
const firestoreTimestamp = firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

Is this possible with firebase node admin sdk? I tried the following:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
const firestoreTimestamp = firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

But this give the error:

```
  [ts] Property 'Timestamp' does not exist on type 'typeof firestore'.
```